# Angular JS with HANA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hana

I have been trying to run a Angular JS application which is located in HANA. Since the Web IDE does not support Angular JS development, I have the application in Webstorm editor locally in my laptop.I am using a Resource override plug in to direct the location of my files towards local files. However when I run the index.html from the HANA server, I am getting HTTP 404 error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have two files in the folder to allow web access:

- .xsaccess [see content guide here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/400066065a1b46cf91df0ab436404ddc/2.0.02/en-US/5fe3b123826d4503aa66eb955a002821.html)
- .xsapp (empty file)